# Problems with creation of database DVWA

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, security

I am trying to set up Damn Vulnerable Web App (DVWA) (www.dvwa.co.uk).

I installed XAMPP according to these instruction : http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html
I installed DVWA according to these instructions: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzIj07jt8rM

I went to localhost/dvwa and see:
Unable to connect to the database.

```
 mysql_error()
```

I try to setup database, it shows **"Could not connect to the database - please check the config file".**

The `/htdocs/dvwa/config/config.inc.php` file shows:

```
$_DVWA[ 'db_server' ] = 'localhost';

$_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';

$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ] = 'root';

$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = 'p@ssw0rd';
```

I tried replacing `localhost with 127.0.0.1` but it still did not work.

How I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue with it.

**To Fix it**

You must go to DVWA Directory>>Config>> Open config.inc.php with your favorite text editor.

then for   `$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = 'p@ssw0rd';` change the password to `''` and then it should be fixed.

Comment: Change the password to Empty!

Answer (score 8):

On my [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) localhost after renaming `config.inc.php.dist` to **`config.inc.php`** and accessing the url `http://localhost/dvwa/setup.php` I was seeing the error:

```
Unable to connect to the database.
```

---

Followed the steps:

- Following [Installing Damn Vulnerable Web Application (DVWA) on Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cak2lQvBRAo) within `config.inc.php` changed the password to **`blank`**, effectively changed the line:

  ```
  $_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = 'p@ssw0rd';
  ```

  to:

  ```
  $_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '';
  ```

The issue still persisted as:

```
Could not connect to the database service.
Please check the config file.
Database Error #1045: Access denied for user 'dvwa'@'localhost' (using password: NO).
```

---

### Solution

Changing the `db_user` from **`dvwa`** to **`root`** solved the issue. So effectively you need to change the line:

```
$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'dvwa';
```

to:

```
$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'root';
```

Snapshot:

[image: DVWA]

Answer (score 6):

That error message occurs in DVWA if `mysql_connect()` fails. Possible reasons include:

- MySQL service is not running. Start the service:

  ```
  \xampp\mysql_start.bat
  ```
- MySQL service is running on a non-default port.  If so, add the port to your hostname:

  ```
  $_DVWA['db_server'] = '127.0.0.1:3306'; // or whatever port you use
  ```
- Username or password are incorrect. Verify them in XAMPP's phpMyAdmin instance.

Answer (score 2):

Record my solution for my issue:

change

```
$_DVWA[ 'db_server' ]   = '127.0.0.1';
$_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';
$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'root';
$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = 'p@ssw0rd';
```

to

```
$_DVWA[ 'db_server' ]   = 'localhost';
$_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';
$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'root';
$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply Remove the password from the mysql configuration;

```
**$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '';**
```

like that it'll be work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file `/htdocs/dvwa/config/config.inc.php` in a text editor. Find the line `$_DVWA[ 'db_port '] = '3306'` and make sure the port is `3306`.

Comment: Upvote. For some reason, the default conf.php has mysql selected and the default port for postgres. Also, changing 127.0.0.1 to localhost makes a difference. I'm on php7.1.6

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your mariaDB root password to the same password of DVWA (`$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ]`)  config.inc.php. To do that follow the steps described at **Step 4 — Changing the Root Password** at: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password

Also, executes the steps described at: https://github.com/ethicalhack3r/DVWA#database-setup

More especifically:

```
mysql> create database dvwa;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> grant all on dvwa.* to dvwa@localhost identified by 'xxx';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

So Stop all the xampp modules, quit xampp, open again, start and try again.

Good luck!

Att.,

JLU.

Answer (score 1):

First go to `C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\config\config.inc.php` or similar path on your OS.

Set password to empty string:

`$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '';`

I just went to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ and then clicked on User accounts

[image: step-1]

Then I created a new user account with these settings:

[image: step-2]

Then clicked this button to finish:

[image: step-3]

Then I opened http://localhost/dvwa/setup.php back and click Create/Reset Database.

[image: step-4]

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I have provided a detailed explanation on StackExchange. The link is as followed.

https://security.stackexchange.com/a/48125/36726

**Quick fix:**

1. Stop the XAMPP control panel.
2. Go to ..\XAMPP\mysql
3. Find resetroot.bat and execute it.
4. Proceed with entering random key when prompted.
5. Restart XAMPP control panel.

Now, when you try to connect to DVWA, the browser should land you on the Login Page.

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

you can also give the mysql server password config.inc.php file.

suppose my mysql password is `12345` so I've changed `config.inc.php` file like

```
$_DVWA[ 'db_server' ] = 'localhost';

$_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';

$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ] = 'root';

$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '12345';
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a database with `mysql` use:

```
mysql -u root -p

use mysql;

create database dvwa;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem & this worked for me:-
Just change `$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = 'p@ssw0rd';`
to `$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '';`

You just have to remove the password.